# How to use a variable in .html() in an .each() loop when handling Ajax JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, variables

I'm not even sure if this is possible...

I'm using the following jquery code to handle some AJAX JSON data, and it works fine...

```
       data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    $('textarea#bec_term_id').html(data.bec_term_newlines_term_id); 
    $('textarea#bec_name').html(data.bec_term_newlines_name); 
    $('textarea#bec_slug').html(data.bec_term_newlines_slug); 
    $('textarea#bec_description').html(data.bec_term_newlines_description);
```

But I want to dynamically create the above (Reason? because it's just a shortened version of the full code which has an unknown number of possible additional rows).

The method I'm trying to use is:

```
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    var columnslist  = [  'term_id', 'name', 'slug', 'description'];  // plus others

    $.each(columnslist, function(index, colname) {
          $('textarea#bec_' + colname ).html(data.'bec_term_newlines_' + colname);  
    });
```

But it doesn't work.

It's this last part (marked') of the  .html(data. ) that is causing the difficulty.

Does anyone know how, if at all, a variable can be used in such a context? And if not, is there any other way to achieve the same end?

Answer (score 1):

Use `[]` to pass a var

```
$('textarea#bec_' + colname ).html(data['bec_term_newlines_' + colname]);
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo! God bless u2!

Answer (score 1):

Use square bracket notation

```
$('textarea#bec_' + colname ).html(data['bec_term_newlines_' + colname]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use strings for accessors like you are doing in JavaScript, but you can use bracket notation:

```
.html(data['bec_term_newlines_' + colname]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also be able interested in the `dataType` setting of `$.ajax`.

From the [api documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>
> Type: String
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none
>   is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of
>   the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield
>   a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and
>   anything else will be returned as a string).

You could probably set it to `'json'` to avoid that `data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` line.

Comment: thanks Eric, but I think that's beyond me at the moment! My code's working now so I'm leave it well alone. Thanks for posting though. Hope it helps the next guy...